# Parsing web page source code with regex

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I can't seem to figure out the regular expression I need in order to parse the following.

```
<div id="MustBeInThisId">
   <div class="ValueFromThisClass">
      The Value I need
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have a wrapping div with an id. That div contain multiple other divs but only one of those divs I need the value from.

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Oh, what should I use? I'm using PHP by the way. Edit: noticed the link... thanks Edit 2: That's nice and all but it doesn't stop me from needed the ability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to extract some data from an HTML document, you should not use regular expressions.

Instead, you should use a DOM Parser : those are made exactly for that.

In PHP, you would use the **`DOMDocument`** class, and its [**`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method, to load the HTML content.

Then, you can work with methods such as :

- [`DOMDocument::getElementById()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to get an element if you know its `id`,
- [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to get all elements which have a given tag.

You can even work with [**`DOMXpath`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to execute XPath queries on your HTML content -- which will allow you to search for pretty much anything in it.

In your case, I suppose that something like this should do the trick.

First, get your HTML content into a string *(or use [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php))* :

```
$html = <<<HTML
<p>hello</p>
<div>
    <div id="MustBeInThisId">
    <div class="ValueFromThisClass">
        The Value I need
    </div>
    </div>
<div>
HTML;
```

Then, load it to a `DOMDocument` instance :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

Instanciate a `DOMXPath` object, and use it to query your DOM object :

*My XPath expression might be a bit more complex than necessary... I'm not really good with those...*

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query('//div[@id="MustBeInThisId"]/div[@class="ValueFromThisClass"]');
```

And, finally, work with the results of that query :

```
if ($items->length > 0) {
    var_dump( trim( $items->item(0)->nodeValue ) );
}
```

And here is your result :

```
string 'The Value I need' (length=16)
```

Comment: Great solution but unfortunate the HTML I'm loading isn't completely valid so `loadHTML` is throwing errors. Edit: I take that back, they are warnings not errors, so I can suppress them.

Comment: You should be able to make those disappear, using the **`@` operator** *(it's generally not a good idea using it, though)*, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php ;; or with the **`libxml` functions**, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) - it will make your life much, much easier.

```
$html = str_get_html($source_code);
$tag = $html->find("#MustBeInThisId .ValueFromThisClass", 0);
$the_value_i_need = $tag->innertext;
```

Comment: That was what I was using until I came to the situation that I need to pass cookies and a user agent.

Comment: You were possibly using `file_get_html()` - notice that the code example I put there is using `str_get_html()`. You can pass it any string, from whatever you use to acquire the source code - for instance, you could use the cURL bindings to pass cookies/UA, and then take the resulting source code and pass it to `str_get_html()`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex can't parse HTML since HTML isn't a regular language. You should use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Then you get nice functions like `getElementById` :)

Answer (score 0):

Or try a javascript library like [JQuery](http://jquery.com/). I think it's the easiest way to do vhat you want.